# Getting all open connections within a docker image

Tags: session, ubuntu, docker

I am conneting to a docker image with a remote desktop connection. Xubuntu is running on this image. If one closes the remote app by pressing x the session the session will continue.

Which means that several sessions are running on the same docker image, seperated by the ports. Is there the possibility to see which ports are still connected to an open session from inse the docker image itself.

Thank you for you help

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not clear to me, but I will try to answer. Actually you can be "connected" to a running container which is based on some docker image. You want to check the port of your running container ? You need to access to the host of your docker container and run `docker ps`. If you want to check what are the running processes in your container => `docker top CONTAINER_NAME`.